# Capture portion of string after specific characters using Regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "FirstName LastName - 1234xx"
```

In above case, want to replace above string with everything after " - " substring. In the above example it would mean changing `str` to `1234xx`

The length of string after " - " is not fixed, hence cannot just capture last certain no. of characters

This approach gives `FirstName LastName -  -` instead of desired output `1234xx`

```
public class StringExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "FirstName LastName - 1234xx";
        String newStr = str.replaceAll("(?<=( - )).*", "$1");

        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: `String newStr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" - ") + 3);` if you just have to have a regex try `String newStr = str.replaceAll("(.*)(\\s+-\\s+)(.*)$", "$3");`

Comment: Heck, even `#split` takes a regex that would be the same simplicity: `String[] parts = str.split(" - "); String newStr = parts[1];`

Comment: What if there is more than one `-` in the string? For example `String test = "what do i do - now? - blablabla"`